# why is my program running both the if and else conditions?

Tags: c++, c, if-statement

I am a newbie to coding. its been like 2 to 3 weeks since I started learning c language. I have learnt using if and else statements from Youtube tutorials and made this small block of code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
  float c,f;
main()
{
     int t=2;
     int o;
     printf("select any one option by entering '1' or '3'  \n 1. celcius to farenheit  \n 3. farenheit to celcius  \n enter any option ");
     scanf("%d",&o);
        if(t<o)
         { 
          printf(" \n enter the value of temperature in celcius ");
          scanf("%f",&c);
          f=(c*1.8)+32;
          printf(" \n the value of temperature of %f celcius in farenheit is %f ",c,f);
         }
        else(t>o);
         {
          printf("  \n enter the value of temperature in farenheit ");
          scanf("%f",&f);
          c=(f-32)/1.8;
          printf("  \n the value of temperature of %f farenheit in celcius is %f ",f,c);
         }
         return 0;
}
```

I have also tried this way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 float c,f;
 
main()
{
     int o;
     printf("select any one option by entering 'a' or 'b'  \n 1. celcius to farenheit  \n 2. farenheit to celcius  \n enter any option ");
     scanf("%d",&o);
        if(o=1)
         { 
          printf(" \n enter the value of temperature in celcius ");
          scanf("%f",&c);
          f=(c*1.8)+32;
          printf(" \n the value of temperature of %f celcius in farenheit is %f ",c,f);
         }
        else(o=2);
         {
          printf("  \n enter the value of temperature in farenheit ");
          scanf("%f",&f);
          c=(f-32)/1.8;
          printf("  \n the value of temperature of %f farenheit in celcius is %f ",f,c);
         }
}
```

so the problem is this code is running both the conditions one after the other. so please critique this and also recommend me some good beginner c language self learning books or tutorials if you have any. thank you.

Comment: `if(o=1)` ==> `if (o == 1)` ... assignment versus comparison

Comment: The `(t>o)` in your else is wrong syntax. The right syntax is `if (something) { blablabla; } else { blobloblo; }` There is no condition after the `else`, it is immediately followed by [the block of] code.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly:

```
else(o=2); // <-- notice the semicolon
{
      printf("  \n enter the value of temperature in farenheit ");
      scanf("%f",&f);
      c=(f-32)/1.8;
      printf("  \n the value of temperature of %f farenheit in celcius is %f ",f,c);
}
```

Will get elvauate to:

```cpp
else
{
    o = 2;
}
// this will run no matter the condition
{
      printf("  \n enter the value of temperature in farenheit ");
      scanf("%f",&f);
      c=(f-32)/1.8;
      printf("  \n the value of temperature of %f farenheit in celcius is %f ",f,c);
}
```

Secondly, `if(o=1)` assign `o` with `1`, and because `o` is a nonzero value, `if(o=1)` will return `true` everytime.
You should use `==` instead.

Thirdly, you `else` has the wrong systax, `else` systax look like this

```cpp
if (somecondition)
{
   // code
}
else
{
   // code
}
```

Base on what you write, you should use `else if` instead

You code should look like this:

```cpp
if(o == 1)
{
    // code
}
else if(o == 2)
{
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a `;` after else which you need to remove.

```
else//;REMOVED THIS SEMICOLON and no need to pass arguments or use else if
```

Note in your 1st code snippet in the `else` syntax you don't need to use `()` . Second you had  a semicolon `;` after the `else` which need not be there.

And in your 2nd code snippet you are using `=` while you should be using `==` .

You can use `else if` for your 1st code snippet as follows:

```
else if(t > o)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the equality condition you need to substitute the `=` with `==`.
In addition you can also use the else-if statement, so your code will be:

```
if(t<o){
    //actions
}
else if(t>o){
    //actions
}
```

Comment: _"So your code will be: "_ - nothing?

Comment: @Llama I corrected the answer